# Rearrange x-axis of hour when plotting

Tags: r, plot, axis, lattice

I have a record of activities by six groups of people which looks like this:

```
grp hour intensity
1   0   0.048672391
2   0   0.264547556
3   0   0.052459840
4   0   0.078953270
5   0   0.239357060
6   0   0.078163513
1   1   0.029673036
2   1   0.128206479
3   1   0.030184495
4   1   0.076848385
5   1   0.061325717
6   1   0.039264419
1   2   0.020177515
2   2   0.063696611
3   2   0.023759638
4   2   0.047865380
5   2   0.030226285
6   2   0.021652375
...
```

and I make a multiple-line graph out of it:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(intensity ~ hour, groups= grp, type= 'l', data= df)
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

but it doesn't follow people's life cycle. I'm trying to relocate hour 0-4 at the right end of x-axis. Anybody with some ideas? Thanks a lot!

Update:
I tried to change hour to a factor but the output didn't look good enough: the lines are cut off between 2300 - 0000 and there are three parallel 'baselines' out of no where beside the six lines.

```
df$hour <- as.factor(df$hour)
hourder <- levels(df$hour)
df$hour <- factor(df$hour, levels= c(hourder[6:24], hourder[1:5]))
xyplot(intensity ~ hour, groups= grp, type= 'l', data= df)
```

[image]

Comment: You could change time to a factor and then order it with the `levels` argument.

Comment: Thanks, @TylerRinker ! It sounds like a plausible plan while it turns out with some flaws, as updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `ggplot` along with sample data consisting of only two groups for reasons of clarity. The approach using the `levels` argument from the `factor` function suggested by Tyler Rinker is absolutely right.

```
# Required packages
library(ggplot2) 

# Initialize RNG
set.seed(10)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
  grp = as.character(rep(1:2, 24)), 
  hour = rep(0:23, each = 2), 
  intensity = runif(2 * 24, min = 0, max = .8)
)

# Plot sample data
ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = intensity, group = grp, colour = grp), data = df) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x = "Time [h]", y = "Intensity") + 
  scale_color_manual("Groups", values = c("1" = "red", "2" = "blue"))
```

[image: regular_time]

Now, let's adjust the time scale!

```
# Now, reorder your data according to a given index
index <- c(5:23, 0:4)
df$hour <- factor(df$hour, levels = as.character(index), ordered = T)

# Plot sample data with reordered x-axis
ggplot(aes(x = hour, y = intensity, group = grp, colour = grp), data = df) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual("Groups", values = c("1" = "red", "2" = "blue"))
```

[image: shifted_time]

Let me know if it works ;-)

Comment: Many thanks! It really works and I guess something's wrong with lattice... ggplot2 is truly a better package!